# C++ class for use complex numbers multiplication and return two values

Tags: c++

I have a problem with my class witch I use for complex numbers. I want to multiplication two complex numbers and I want to return two values (re, im). I use overload operator but I don't known how to return two values. I woudl like to use this formula `(a1 + b1i) ∗ (a2 + b2i) = (a1a2 − b1b2 + (a1b2 +a2b1)i)`. I want return  re + im.

This is my code:

```
class Complex{
private:
    double realteil;
    double imaginearteil;
public:
    Complex(){
        imaginearteil=0;
        realteil=0;
    }

    Complex(double real): realteil(real){
        imaginearteil = 0;
    }

    Complex(double real, double imaginear){
        this -> realteil = real;
        this -> imaginearteil = imaginear;
    }

    double abs() const{
        double result = this -> realteil * this -> realteil + this -> imaginearteil * this -> imaginearteil;
        result = pow(result,0.5);
        return result;
    }

    Complex konjugiert() const{
        Complex result;
        result.realteil = this -> realteil;
        result.imaginearteil = this -> imaginearteil - 2*imaginearteil;
        return result;
    }

    Complex operator + (const Complex &c){
        Complex result;
        result.realteil = this -> realteil + c.realteil;
        result.imaginearteil = this -> imaginearteil + c.imaginearteil;
        return result;
    }

    Complex operator - (const Complex &c){
        Complex result;
        result.realteil = this -> realteil - c.realteil;
        result.imaginearteil = this -> imaginearteil - c.imaginearteil;
        return result;
    }

    Complex operator * (const Complex &b){
        return ((this -> realteil * b.realteil) - (this -> imaginearteil * b.imaginearteil))
               - ((this -> realteil * b.imaginearteil) + (b.realteil * this -> imaginearteil));



    }

    Complex operator / (const Complex &b){ }


    ostream& printPolar(ostream&) const{
        double temp = realteil*realteil + imaginearteil*imaginearteil;
        double r = pow(temp,0.5);
        double Q;
        if(r == 0){
            Q=0;
        }
        if(imaginearteil >=0) {
            Q = acos(realteil/r);
        }
        if(imaginearteil < 0){
            Q = -acos(realteil/r);
        }


    }



    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& output, const Complex& a);

};

ostream& operator << (ostream& output, const Complex& a){
    if(a.imaginearteil == 0)
        output << a.realteil;

    if(a.imaginearteil < 0)
        output << a.realteil <<a.imaginearteil<<"i";

    if(a.imaginearteil > 0)
        output << a.realteil <<"+" <<a.imaginearteil<<"i";

    return output;
}


int main() {

    Complex a,b(3),c(7,2),d(1.5,-3.2);

    cout <<c<<endl;
    cout <<c.konjugiert();
    a = c*d;

    cout << a;


    //cout<<a<<" "<<b<<" "<<c<<" "<<d<<endl;
    // Complex x=(b+2)*(c-d.abs())/(b-c.konjugiert()*d);

    return 0;
}
```

I want do this in `main()`

```
Complex a,b(3),c(7,2),d(1.5,-3.2);

cout<<a<<" "<<b<<" "<<c<<" "<<d<<endl;

Complex x=(b+2)*(c-d.abs())/(b-c.konjugiert()*d);

cout<<x<<" ";

x.printPolar(cout);

cout<<endl;
```

I woudl like except this result:

```
0 3 7+2i 1.5-3.2i

0.363472-0.698001i (0.786967,-1.0907)

1-3.5i
```

Another question, how to retrun two values `Q,r` from `ostream& printPolar(ostream&) const`?

Comment: You have already done this in `operator+` and `operator-`.

Comment: And how to use this property? I do edit my question and I put result.

Comment: It should return `Complex`, is it? But if you insist, you can use `std::tie`.

Comment: Why on earth would you not do it exactly like you have done `operator +`?

Comment: Neither your `operator /` nor `printPolar` have defined behavior. Both claim to return a `std::ostream&` and neither actually do so. I'd fix that first.

Comment: @WhozCraig  how do I do exactly?

Comment: Is this even *your code* ? Your friended `operator <<` already demonstrates how to "do that".

Comment: FWIW, it is imaginaer (imaginär), not imaginear.

Comment: Incidentally.  As you have it at the moment, `Complex(1.0,0) + 1.0` will work, but `1.0 + Complex(1.0,0)` will not.  You should either make all constructors explicit, or make `operator +=` member functions, and then make `operator +` as `operator +(Complex lhs, const Complex& rhs) { return lhs += rhs;}`

Comment: @MartinBonner Can you explain what exactly you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Complex operator * (const Complex &b) const {
  Complex result(
    realteil * b.realteil - imaginearteil*b.imaginearteil,  // real part
    realteil * b.imaginearteil + b.realteil * imaginearteil // img part
    );

   return result;
}
```

I omitted the explicit use of ``*this->*'' operator.